# Separated, Sorted d3 Circles displayed along the X axis

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to achieve the following display utilizing the d3js.org library:
[image]

I get the circle svg objects to display with varying radius based on an attribute I'm getting from the JSON, but where I'm getting stuck is grouping them together and displaying along a linear, horizontal axis.

Here is my JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "category" : "Foo",
        "radius" : "3"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Bar",
        "radius" : "2"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Foo",
        "radius" : "3"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Bar",
        "radius" : "1"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Bar",
        "radius" : "2"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Foo",
        "radius" : "1"
    }
]
```

d3 Javascript

```
var height = 50,
    width = 540;

var companyProfileVis = d3.select(".myDiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")

d3.json("data/myData.json", function(data){

    companyProfileVis.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius * 4; })
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.radius * 20; })
            .attr("cy", 20)

});
```

And finally my HTML

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Pablo's answer a bit, you would also need to sort the values in the grouped elements to achieve the order you have in the picture. The code would look like this.

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.category; })
  .sortValues(function(a, b) { return b.radius - a.radius; })
  .entries(data);
```

The [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) based on this would look as follows.

```
var gs = svg.selectAll("g").data(nested)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (20 + i * 100) + ")"; });
gs.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("circle");
```

Note that you're moving the `g` elements according to the index, so you don't have to worry about the `y` coordinate of the circles later. The `x` coordinate is computed based on the index similar to how the `y` coordinate is computed for the `g`.

All that you then have to do is set a few more attributes and append the `text` elements. Complete demo [here](https://vida.io/documents/djpsuzkBY2khW384u).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`d3.nest`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) to group the data items by category, and then use [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) to create both groups of circles.

```
// Nest the items by category
var nestedData = d3.nest(data)
   .key(function(d) { return d.category; })
   .map(data, d3.map)
   .values();
```

This will give you the following array:

```
nestedData = [
  [
    {category: "Foo", radius: "3"},
    {category: "Foo", radius: "3"},
    {category: "Foo", radius: "1"}
  ],
  [
    {category: "Bar", radius: "2"},
    {category: "Bar", radius: "1"},
    {category: "Bar", radius: "2"}
  ]
]
```

Regards,